# Integrating over a square in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, geometry

I am trying to integrate a Dirac delta function over the unit square $S$ in polar coordinates
$$
\delta(f(r_i,r_j,\theta_i,\theta_j))
$$
**I must use the polar coordinate system**. I've broken the square up into triangles to avoid any discontinuities at the corners. But is there an easier way to set up the limits i.e.
$$
\int_{\theta_j^{-}}^{\theta_j^{+}} \int_{\theta_i^{-}}^{\theta_i^{+}} \int_{0}^{f(r_j)} \int_{0}^{f(r_i)} \textrm{d}r_i \textrm{d}r_j\textrm{d}\theta_i \textrm{d}\theta_j = \int_{S} \int_{S} \textrm{d}\mathbf{r}_i\textrm{d}\mathbf{r}_j
$$
so that I integrate over $S$? **Notice I am trying to integrate over all *pairs* of points in the square**.
[image]

Comment: by symmetry it is enough to integrate over one triangle given by the diagonal and two of the corners of the square. this reduces the number of integrals by a factor of two.

Comment: u also might like this:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122135/average-distance-to-a-random-point-in-a-rectangle-from-an-arbitrary-point/1122286#1122286